# How to insert new line on return key press in iMessage on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, messages

Does anyone know if it is possible in iMessage on Mac OSX to set the return key to go to the next line instead of sending the message?

Comment: Have you tried Shift+Enter? Are you looking for the key combo to do it, or to replace the return key functionality altogether

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: My apologies, I was thinking on the fly. Either Option+Return OR Control+Return will do the trick.

Comment: This question didn't yet received a correct answer but a workaround. I found a partial answer which looks like a better ergonomic design: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/236255/22003 .

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> to enter a new line.

Edit: Added additional key combo re: smoooosher's comment to the OP

Comment: I found one more funny workaround: [ctrl]+[Q], [return]. •••• This is a good way to remind the function of [ctrl]+[Q].

Comment: @danielAzuelos What does control-Q do?

Comment: @larsmoa, The comment made by daniel Azuelos does indeed work and it's ⌘Q not ^Q that quits an application!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I will delete previous comment

Comment: I always forget this because Slack is the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried CTRL+Enter and it worked

Comment: This is the same as the solution that was posted a year ago July.

Answer (score 1):

There is no preference available to control that, but I wonder if you could override the event associated with the Enter key? The following command maps the Enter key to a menu item command. You'd just need to replace the command with "insert new line"... somehow.

```
defaults write com.apple.iChat NSUserKeyEquivalents "{ 'New Message' = '\\U000a'; }"
```

To undo your change later:

```
defaults delete com.apple.iChat NSUserKeyEquivalents
```

References:

1. http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html
2. /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict

Comment: `New Message` isn't the function activated by the `[return]`. •••• The code sent to the application by the `[return]` is `\U000d` and not `\U000a` •••• I didn't find any finished answer along these hints.

Answer (score -1):

Holding down "Shift" + "Option" (Left side - not right, it doesn't work on that side for me) will create spacing between paragraphs without sending the msg

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

For me the solution in iMessage:
<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This is the same as the solution that was posted a year ago July.